# Should questions about improving the performance of scripts be on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I was looking at [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/322942/how-to-use-awk-to-query-a-file-loaded-with-mapfile) question in particular and wondering whether it would be better suited to Code Review SE than here.  It's about shell scripting, which is on topic here and so I don't have a big issue with it being asked here.

On the other hand, it is a piece of functioning code (though a comment there makes me wonder if that's true, but the point of the question is about a working piece of code).  Given that it's about trying to improve the performance of a working piece of code, that would (also?) be on topic at Code Review.

I know some questions can be on topic in many sites and it's up to the questioner to pick where they think it belongs, but should we try to migrate such questions or keep them here?

Comment: Seems fine to keep this here, IMO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I appreciate the sentiment behind code golf and UUOC awards, it's rare that the common, everyday scripting question on here suffers extensive runtime because of an extra process. Having said that, though, I would appreciate seeing creative solutions (with comparative benchmarks) for solving problems that *are* constrained, performance-wise.

I could go either way, but I lean towards "keep".